# Transit visa for Indian citizen traveling through Hong Kong

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, hong-kong

I am an Indian national with a valid Indian passport. I intend to travel to San Francisco (US) via Hong Kong with Singapore Airlines and Cathay Pacific. I have to transit through Hong Kong without exiting the airport transit area within 2 hours.

Do I need a transit visa (pre-arrival registration) for Hong Kong for this short duration?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a visa if you remain in the international area of the airport and your layover is less than 48 hours. You do not need pre-arrival registration unless you intend to enter Hong Kong.

From Timatic:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward (Air-to-Air or Air-to-Sea) ticket to a third country within 48 hours. They must stay in the international transit area and have documents required for the next destination.